# jQuery filter - sort by attribute and sort by price

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, filter

I'm trying to create dropdown that filters content.
I have two different types of filters in this:
1) filter that sorts by price
2) filter that sorts by attribute that is tagged in the product.

I'm new to implementing this type of request.
I have the two semi-working, but it seems like the two filters are conflicting with each other. For example: If I filter by price first, and then try to filter by attribute (dropdown), it doesn't filter correctly. But it filters correctly if I just filter down either by price or just by dropdown.

Also, right now I have the price filtering as buttons, but I would like the price to be in a separate dropdown as well. I'd also like to add "best seller" as an attribute in there, and I just tag the products in terms of best-selling. 
Is this possible?

Can someone help? Take a look?

Thanks for any and all help!

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/daysable/eags255n/

My code is below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>
 <p>What speed do you need? </p>
<button id="asc"> sort by price asd</button><button id="desc"> sort by price desc</button>

      <p>What speed bike do you need? </p>
       <select class="filterby">
        <option value="all"><h5>See All</h5></option>
        <option value="15"><h5>15</h5></option>
        <option value="20"><h5>20</h5></option>
        <option value="25"><h5>25</h5></option>
        <option value="50"><h5>50</h5></option>
        <option value="150"><h5>150</h5></option>
        <option value="160"><h5>160</h5></option>
      </select> 
      <p>What do you like to watch? </p>
        <select class="filterby">
        <option value="all"><h5>See all packages</h5></option>
        <option value="showtime"><h5>Showtime</h5></option>
        <option value="hbo"><h5>HBO</h5></option>
        <option value="cinemax"><h5>Cinemax</h5></option>
        <option value="starz"><h5>Starz</h5></option>
        <option value="ondemand"><h5>On Demand</h5></option>
      </select>      

      <p>Do you want a contract? </p>
        <select class="filterby">
        <option value="all"><h5>See all deals?</h5></option>
        <option value="contract"><h5>Contract</h5></option>
        <option value="nocontract"><h5>No Contract</h5></option>
      </select>
   </ul>
   <div class="FilterSorting">
 <div id="FilterContainer">
<!-- CARD 1 -->
<li class="ux-offer all ondemand hbo 50 contract">
<div class="offer">
  <p class="offer-lob">50 mph</p>
<div class="container"> 
   <div class="offer-price">
   <p class="title">Bike 1</p>
   <p class="ux-priceoffer">
     <span class="ux-priceoffer--currency">$</span> 
     <span class="ux-priceoffer--dollars">89</span> 
     <span class="ux-priceoffer--cents">99/mo</span>
     <span class="ux-priceoffer--duration">for 12 mo.</span>
   </p>
    <a class="ux-button" href="#">Add to cart</a>
  </div>
</div>
</li>

<!-- CARD 2 -->
<li class="ux-offer all showtime 15 nocontract">
<div class="offer">
  <p class="offer-lob">15 mph</p>
<div class="container"> 
   <div class="offer-price">
   <p class="title">Bike 2</p>
   <p class="ux-priceoffer">
     <span class="ux-priceoffer--currency">$</span> 
     <span class="ux-priceoffer--dollars">44</span> 
     <span class="ux-priceoffer--cents">99/mo</span>
     <span class="ux-priceoffer--duration">for 6 mo.</span>
   </p>
    <a class="ux-button" href="#">Add to cart</a>
  </div>
</div>
</li>
<!-- CARD 3 -->
<li class="ux-offer all ondemand cinemax 20 contract">
<div class="offer">
  <p class="offer-lob">20 mph</p>
<div class="container"> 
   <div class="offer-price">
   <p class="title">Bike 3</p>
   <p class="ux-priceoffer">
     <span class="ux-priceoffer--currency">$</span> 
     <span class="ux-priceoffer--dollars">109</span> 
     <span class="ux-priceoffer--cents">99/mo</span>
     <span class="ux-priceoffer--duration">for 6 mo.</span>
   </p>
    <a class="ux-button" href="#">Add to cart</a>
  </div>
</div>
</li>
<!-- CARD 4 -->
<li class="ux-offer all hbo 150 contract">
<div class="offer">
  <p class="offer-lob">150 mph</p>
<div class="container"> 
   <div class="offer-price">
   <p class="title">Bike 4</p>
   <p class="ux-priceoffer">
     <span class="ux-priceoffer--currency">$</span> 
     <span class="ux-priceoffer--dollars">80</span> 
     <span class="ux-priceoffer--cents">99/mo</span>
     <span class="ux-priceoffer--duration">for 12 mo.</span>
   </p>
    <a class="ux-button" href="#">Add to cart</a>
  </div>
</div>
</li>

<!-- CARD 5 -->
<li class="ux-offer all showtime starz 25 nocontract">
<div class="offer">
  <p class="offer-lob">25 mph</p>
<div class="container"> 
   <div class="offer-price">
   <p class="title">Bike 5</p>
   <p class="ux-priceoffer">
     <span class="ux-priceoffer--currency">$</span> 
     <span class="ux-priceoffer--dollars">220</span> 
     <span class="ux-priceoffer--cents">99/mo</span>
     <span class="ux-priceoffer--duration">for 12 mo.</span>
   </p>
    <a class="ux-button" href="#">Add to cart</a>
  </div>
</div>
</li>
<!-- CARD 6 -->
<li class="ux-offer all hbo starz ondemand 160 contract">
<div class="offer">
  <p class="offer-lob">160 mph</p>
<div class="container"> 
   <div class="offer-price">
   <p class="title">Bike 6</p>
   <p class="ux-priceoffer">
     <span class="ux-priceoffer--currency">$</span> 
     <span class="ux-priceoffer--dollars">50</span> 
     <span class="ux-priceoffer--cents">99/mo</span>
     <span class="ux-priceoffer--duration">for 3 mo.</span>
   </p>
    <a class="ux-button" href="#">Add to cart</a>
  </div>
</div>
</li>
</div>
</body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$("select.filterby").change(function(){
    var filters = $.map($("select.filterby").toArray(), function(e){
        return $(e).val();
    }).join(".");
    $("div#FilterContainer").find("li.ux-offer").hide();
    $("div#FilterContainer").find("li." + filters).show();
});
</script>

<script>
function sortByPrice(a,b){
    return $(a).find('.ux-priceoffer').text() > $(b).find('.ux-priceoffer').text();
}

function sortByPriceDesc(a,b){
   return $(a).find('.ux-priceoffer').text() < $(b).find('.ux-priceoffer').text();
}

function reorderEl(el){
    var container = $('.FilterSorting');
    container.html('');
    el.each(function(){
        $(this).appendTo(container);
    });
}
$('#asc').click(function(){
    reorderEl($('.ux-offer').sort(sortByPrice));
});

$('#desc').click(function(){
    reorderEl($('.ux-offer').sort(sortByPriceDesc));
});
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: It might be helpful if you create a jsFiddle of your code and then link back to it in this question https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Ahh thank you for the tip! I've added the fiddle to the original post.

Comment: Your sort by prices does not work in either case, that might be a place to start

Comment: see this fiddle I made some changes to sortByPrice method: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lz0nf62m/)
use something similar. This is not answer to this question. But you can get some hint.

Comment: thank you so much for this change, it seems to work smoothly, accept for when sorting desc, it doesn't sort the 3 digit prices correctly (they fall to the bottom), do you know why that is?

Comment: @KristinMann see this fiddle: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lz0nf62m/1/). hope this helps you.

Comment: @govindpatel, thank you so much. This works wonderfully. Last question, do you know how I can get Sort by price in a drop down instead of the buttons?

Comment: @KristinMann, see this fiddle: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lz0nf62m/3/). Is that what you wanted?. I have added a select dropdown.when the user changes that it will call the `$.change()` method. There I am checking the value of the select and calling the sort method based on the selected value. I have also commented the code for you. Hope this helps you. and please like my comments If this is what you wanted. Thank you.

Comment: @govindpatel, Thank you again! this worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so a couple of things, it might be wise to insert this data from somewhere instead of hard-coding it into the html. You could make a text file and read it into an array, even. That way you can get an array of total cost, and run your `.sort` against that since you're doing some weird stuff with payment plans(i.e $x for x months). You will (like I hinted) want to use something like sort over all the elements, that way it will return an entire sorted list, and you can append the entire list.

And of course this isn't the only way to do this, it just seems the most intuitive to me, at least for price, since you actually want to sort the list in ascending or descending order.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback! This is slightly over my head some. Can you help and/or give an example of this? I have never done something along these lines, and a starting point would help. Thank you!

Comment: yeah sure, [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83559/thehumanchatroom) might be easier